# Order by top five repeated IDs

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

There is a table in my database `duplicate_id` which contains multiple ids and also contains many duplicate ids in it. What I have been trying to do is to sort top five ids which are being repeated the most in the table `duplicate_id`. Kindly let me know how can i do that

**Table Structure:** ID | Message

**Expected output:**

ID    |   Number of repeats

201             8

212                  7

205                  5

209                  3

229                  2

Comment: `COUNT()` + `GROUP BY` + `ORDER BY` + `LIMIT` --- I'm sure you can do that yourself ;-)

Comment: Guys, I know you all like reputation points (*my precious...*), but how about giving a chance for OP to get a solution themselves? Well, at least sometimes ;-)

Comment: @soft genic: My, friendly, suggestion to you and I know that from my own experience is that you should measure twice before you cut!:-) Meaning, you should think and do everything you can to solve your problem because it will be better for your knowledge and you won't get these -votes from guys and girls that are just waiting for these kind of questions(let's say simple, but not for everyone). Hope you get it?! Stay strong:-)

Comment: @Sylca Thanks for your friendly advice. Sometimes it happens that you really got confused at a very basic step because it doesnot click in your mind while working. So i think if they dont wanna answer, why to mock on it.  Moreover the query i was trying was without groupby due to which i was getting single row in return i forgot of using that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT ID, COUNT(*) AS `Number of repeats`
FROM duplicate_id
GROUP BY ID
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
LIMIT 5
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the order by so sort your results:

```
Select * from table order by repeats desc limit 5
```

Answer (score 0):

well... try this (I don't know mysql, so I have to guess)

```
select ID, 
       count(*) as 'Number of Repeats'
from   duplicate_ID
group  by ID
order  by 2
```

Another approach would be

```
select ID, 'Number of Repeats'
from (
  select ID, 
         count(*) as 'Number of Repeats'
  from   duplicate_ID
  group by ID
  ) x
order by 'Number of Repeats'
```